# mongodb , wildcard in $in

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb query where i want to get documents if a field has particular value.

`db.collection.find({key:{$in:['value1','value2']}})` if i run above command i get documents containing either 'value1' or 'value2'. but lets just say there are no values. and i search `db.collection.find({key:{$in:[]}})`, nothing is displayed. and `db.collection.find({key:{$in:[*]}})` gives `unexpected token*` which wild card do i use in $in to show all results.?

Comment: Not the clearest example to what you expect to achieve. The **`$in`** operator is analogous to **`$or`** in a simplified sense.  So that is what it does. If your want `*` then that equates to **everything**. Hence no query restriction at all.

Comment: Why not just omit the selection criteria itself -`db.collection.find()`?

Comment: yes, as batscream pointed out, i can omit the query but a lot of other functions depend on the of query params order etc. i need to change a lot of code if omit it completely when no values are present in $in. so i want to work with existing code and make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is logically consistent behavior for `$in`. The query

```
db.collection.find({ "key" : { "$in" : [] } })
```

could be translated as "find all the documents where the value of `key` is one of the values contained in the array `[]`". Since there are no values in the array `[]`, there are no matching documents. If you want to find all of the extant values for `key`, use `.distinct` to return them as an array:

```
db.collection.distinct("key")
```

`.distinct` will use an index if possible.

If you want a query to match all documents, omit the query selector from `.find`:

```
db.collection.find()
```

as suggested in the comments.